# Conditional LEFT INNER JOIN query with a conditional SELECT on the right table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, conditional-statements

Before I type all this, I have tried and tried to find the solution to this from other threads here and by searching google. But I just cant seem to get the answer. I consider myself pretty good with SQL but I just cant seem to get to grips with this problem at all.

I currently have two tables:

[image]

I am trying to get an array of `ref_departments.id` and `ref_departments.department_name`, which will be used as a dropdown on the frontend to populate the `company_department_norm` table. It should best be pointed out at this point that I have no technical issues in creating the dropdown etc - it is being built in the Yii framework and the actual dropdown itself is already in place. My problem is identifying the correct SQL statement to bring back on the data I want for populating the dropdown (I will be using Yii's Chtml helper class).

The first condition of the `SELECT` statement I am looking to create is one where the query on the `ref_departments` table will only select rows where the values in the `id` (PK) column are not found in the `company_department_norm.department_id` column. This done so only valid options are available in the list. I have this query working, and it looks like this...

```
SELECT RD.id, RD.department_name FROM ref_departments RD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN company_department_norm CDN
ON (CDN.department_id = RD.id) 
WHERE (CDN.department_id IS NULL)
```

Additional integrity/data validation for this will also be done on the back end (in the Yii model class).

The next step of this is the part I am totally stuck on. Within the Yii model for `company_department_norm`, the `company_id` field states the FK for the company (as you can see above). This will be passed as a parameter into the query to add an additional condition to the query so that the `JOIN` statement will only match rows on the right table (`company_department_name`) where `company_id` is the same as the `company_id` passed from the model. For testing purposes, I am simply trying to get this working with a `company_id` of integer 1 hard-coded into the SQL statement. However, for the life of me, I just cant seem to work out how to do this.

I have attempted to modify with above query using this: -

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM company_department_norm WHERE 
company_department_norm.company_id = 1) CDN
```

However, this just doesn't seem to filter the right table at all.

Can anyone help me with this? I would imagine that more experienced SQL users than I would be able to identify the solution quite quickly but I have been pulling my hair out for hours trying to solve this!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: And what is your desired output?

Comment: The DBMS I am using is MySQL

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RD.id, RD.department_name 
FROM ref_departments RD
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM company_department_norm 
    WHERE 
        company_id = 1 
    AND department_id = RD.id
)
```

PS: you should consider dropping the `department_name` column of your `company_department_norm` table: [6NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form)

SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/553a4/2

Comment: The DBMS I am using is MySQL.

Comment: Sebas - Thanks for your help but I am getting a error of "Unknown column 'company_department_norm.company_id' in 'where clause'. " using that statement. Any thoughts?

Comment: that's ok, at first I planned to tune your left join that's why i needed to know since mysql needs a special treatment for that. But since i used not exists instead it doesn't really affect the query.

Comment: BTW the 'department_name' column is required (AFAIK from my understanding of normal forms) as the table is a normalisation table to associate the key (which is the text string in the 'department_name' column) against a reference tables of department names. Just a routine normalisation procedure.

Comment: I think the department_name in the company table is not required since the information exists in the department table. As you can see in the user's extracts, there's already an inconsistency: there's a department name stated but no department_id...

Comment: If the FK consists in the 2 fields, you're right. But I don't think it is so.

Comment: Sebas - it's still not working. It is returning an array with the NULL filter but not filtering via company_id at all.

Comment: BTW the 'department_name' is required as the ID to normalise against. This is coming from an XML file and the only ID the company has for the department is a string of the department name. So this string is the only ID I have to normalise.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand you question then. This query shows all departments not related yet to your selected company.

Comment: I almost certainly haven't explained it correctly, forgive me if I haven't. If you can imagine that there is no company ID right now and it is only 1 company. If you do that, the NULL filter is all you need. However, I need it to look at the company ID and return an array specific to that company. i.e. if the company_id in the Yii model is 1, it should only evaluate again rows that have that company_id. So it will look at it and say "Does company of company_id 1 already have this selected? No, OK, return it in the array". So it ignores all other company_ids and is specific to that company.

Comment: ok so, for company 1, nothing should be returned, and for company 2 everything, correct?

Comment: Sebas - can I ask what "SELECT 1 FROM" does? I dont think I have seen it before and it would be useful to know.

Comment: oh, the NOT EXISTS just checking whether there's a result in the subquery. So, to not add any disk reads overhead, selecting "1" or any other static value is perfect. (funcionnally you could select any not null field of company_department_norm instead and it would work)

Answer (score 1):

You can put the company_id condition in the ON clause:

```
SELECT RD.id, RD.department_name FROM ref_departments RD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN company_department_norm CDN
ON (CDN.department_id = RD.id AND CDN.company_id = 1) 
WHERE (CDN.department_id IS NULL)
```

This returns any department that isn't represented yet at company 1, versus your first query returns any department that isn't represented yet at *any* company.

---

Re your comment:  Given your example data, this query won't show any difference between using the company_id condition or not, because both departments *are* represented at company 1.

I have tested this on MySQL 5.5 and it works fine.  Here's another example with more data that demonstrates better:

```
use test;

drop table if exists ref_departments;
create table ref_departments (
 id int primary key,
 department_name varchar(20)
);

insert into ref_departments values
(1, 'Accounts'),
(2, 'HR'),
(3, 'IT');

drop table if exists company_department_norm;
create table company_department_norm (
 id int primary key,
 company_id int,
 department_name varchar(20),
 department_id int
);

insert into company_department_norm values
(1, 1, 'Accounting', 1),
(2, 1, 'HR', 2),
(3, 2, 'Accounts', NULL),
(4, 2, 'HR', NULL),
(5, 2, 'IT', 3);
```

Now query for depts not in company 1, and it correctly shows "IT":

```
SELECT RD.id, RD.department_name FROM ref_departments RD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN company_department_norm CDN
ON (CDN.department_id = RD.id AND CDN.company_id = 1) 
WHERE (CDN.department_id IS NULL);

+----+-----------------+
| id | department_name |
+----+-----------------+
|  3 | IT              |
+----+-----------------+
```

Now query for depts not in company 2.  Even though company 2 *names* Accounts and HR, it doesn't have the numeric department_id on which the join condition is based.  So it thinks those two depts are not matched.

```
SELECT RD.id, RD.department_name FROM ref_departments RD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN company_department_norm CDN
ON (CDN.department_id = RD.id AND CDN.company_id = 2) 
WHERE (CDN.department_id IS NULL);

+----+-----------------+
| id | department_name |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | Accounts        |
|  2 | HR              |
+----+-----------------+
```

If you're getting some other result, you either have not used the query as I described, or your data is not as you described.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for your input. I have tried that statement but, as with Sebas' answer above,  it is returning an array with the NULL filter but not filtering via company_id at all.

Comment: Bill - I tried Sebas' SQLfiddle first and it is working perfectly so I wont try to fix that which is not broken and will go with that, but thank you very much for your input.